# Variable exported from a module not accesible inside function of class in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import, module

I have a file (service file) in angular.I am exporting a variable from it and using it in other file(component.ts).

When i am accessing its value outside the class ,it is working fine  ,but when I am using it inside any function declare inside component class ,it is showing variable not defined.

In angular every module have its own scope ,and ts file converted into js and classes into function.
So according to my understanding of javascript,variable outside of function should be available.
But when i assign it to some declared variable outside the class it is working.

Where am i lacking to understand this behaviour?

```
    import {UserService ,b} from './services/user.service';
    console.log(b);// working
    //var t=b; working

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      providers:[UserService]
    })
    export class AppComponent implements DoCheck , AfterContentInit,AfterContentChecked {
      title = 'project';
      a:any="joshi";
      constructor(private vc: ViewContainerRef ,private user:UserService){
        console.log("parent constr")

      }
      update(){
        //t="changed";  working
        b="changed"  //not working
      this.user.setObservable();

  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: import {UserService ,b} from './services/user.service';
console.log(b);// working
//var t=b; working

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[UserService]
})
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck , AfterContentInit,AfterContentChecked {
  title = 'project';
  a:any="joshi";
  constructor(private vc: ViewContainerRef ,private user:UserService){
    console.log("parent constr")

  }
  update(){
    //t="changed";  working
    b="changed"  //not working
  this.user.setObservable();

Comment: add it in question with formatting

Comment: What type of variable is `b`? And how is it declared in `user.service`?

Comment: export var b="my value"

Comment: @user11561629 Did my post provided enough stuff to be marked as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible because outside a module,a variable is treated as `const`. If it was an object, something like

```
export let b = { name:  "shashank" };
```

you could have been able to change it.

A workaround could be to create a function which can allow you to change its value from the inside of the module itself, something like:

```
export let b = "shashank";

export let setB = (value) => {
  b = value;
}
```

and in `component`:

```
update(){
  setB("Hero");
  console.log(b)
  this.user.setObservable();
}
```

---

That being said, I think you are doing something wrong. The `b` is inside the `UserService`, so it can be used as `this.user.b` rather than importing it explicitly.

The approach you using doesn't seem right (unless you have something more going on and you havent mentioned in the question)

Comment: This is very basic program.I am just trying to understand the functionality of angular.In user.service ,i have declared  export var b="my  value".I don't want workaround ,I want to understand the reason behind this

Comment: @user11561629 : The answer already contains it `That is not possible because outside a module,a variable is treated as const`. This is a behavior of JS and TS.

Comment: @user11561629 : when you create a module, its values are shared across other modules and its values are by default not allowed to be changes directly. The reason you are able to change the value of `object` (if shared) as I have suggested,  is the same as `changing  the value of const` if its an object in `TS`.

Comment: @user11561629 Why are you not using `this.user.b` ?? rather than exporting `b` ? The angular services are created for the same purpose and its a standard practice. I hope I have answered your query

Comment: ,I am doing negative programming ,I know what is right way ,but i want to understand  why framework does not allow in this way, ok,I can console 'b' inside my function ,and es6 modules exports bindings.
If i export object , i can edit its  property and changes are also reflected in user.service means as you said it is treated as const,in case of object i am not changing object reference but only property of object

Comment: @user11561629: when you say `myfunction` , you mean `update()` ?? Yes, you can read `const` values in JS or TS and so it is printed on `console`

Comment: does react and angular follow es6 module behaviour?

Comment: Yes, they should. We are using `TypeScript` which is something more over `es6`.  Please mark it as an answer if it helped  you. and feel free to upvote as well :)

Comment: @user11561629 : did my post qualify to be selected as an answer so that it can be helpful to others as well  ?